# The arcane formals(function(x){})$x

Tags: r, metaprogramming

What is the object `formals(function(x){})$x`?

It's found in the formals of a function, bound to arguments without default value.

Is there any other way to refer to this strange object? Does it have some role other than representing an empty function argument?

Here are some of its properties that can be checked in the console:

```
> is(formals(function(x){})$x)
[1] "name"      "language"  "refObject"
> formals(function(x){})$x

> as.character(formals(function(x){})$x)
[1] ""
```

EDIT: Here are some other ways to get this object:

```
alist(,)[[1]]
bquote()
quote(expr=)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Background: What is `formals(function(x) {})`?

Well, to start with (and as documented in `?formals`) , `formals(function(x) {})` returns a **pairlist**:

```
is(formals(function(x){}))
# [1] "pairlist"
```

Unlike **list** objects, **pairlist** objects can have named elements that contain no value -- a very nice thing when constructing a function that has a possibly optional formal argument.  From `?pairlist`:

> tagged arguments with no value are allowed whereas ‘list’ simply ignores them.

To see the difference, compare `alist()`, which creates pairlists, with `list()` which constructs 'plain old' lists:

```
list(x=, y=2)
# Error in list(x = , y = 2) : argument 1 is empty

alist(x=, y=2)
# $x
# 
# $y
# [1] 2
```

### Your question: What is `formals(function(x) {})$x`?

Now to your question about what `formals(function(x) {})$x` is. My understanding is in some sense its **real** value is the "empty symbol". You can't, however, get at it from within R because the "empty symbol" is an object that R's developers -- very much by design -- try to entirely hide from R users. (For an interesting discussion of the empty symbol, and why it's kept hidden, [see the thread starting here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-February/065915.html)).

When one tries to get at it by indexing an empty-valued element of a pairlist, R's developers foil the attempt by having R return the *name* of the element instead of its verbotten-for-public-viewing *value*. (This is, of course, the **name** object shown in your question).

Comment: Then I must ask what the hell quote(expr=) is! 

identical(quote(expr=), formals(function(x){})$x) == TRUE, 

but

> is(quote(expr=))
[1] "name"      "language"  "refObject"

Comment: Don't know that I can explain it much better than I did, especially in the last two paragraphs above. The **real** value of `quote(expr=)` is the empty symbol, but that's an internal structure that users aren't intended to be playing around with. When you ask to examine it as in your second example, R substitutes in a zero-length name as a placeholder, because the R developers don't want to expose the actual structure/class/typeof etc. of the empty symbol to R end-users. As a result, you don't get to examine the actual internal structure with things like `is`, `class`, `typeof`, `str`, etc.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. I was worried my shorthand for formals(function(x ... wasn't really the same as the empty symbol.

Comment: So, I want to know which parameters of a function don't have default values. Can I compare their values to that "empty symbol"? Or I am not supposed to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It's a `name` or `symbol`, see `?name`, e.g.:

```
is(as.name('a'))
#[1] "name"      "language"  "refObject"
```

The only difference from your example is that you can't use `as.name` to create an empty one.