# When to use pairlists in R?

Tags: r, performance

I know that dotted pairlists aren't used outside of the core language for the most part, but I presumed they are used internally instead of generic vectors for a reason.

Why are pairlists used internally in R, and are there any performance benefits to using pairlists in your own functions?

Comment: This may give you some insight into how and why pairlists are used internally in R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740307/the-arcane-formalsfunctionxx/16740800#16740800

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your second question, I don't think so. [**Section 2.1.11**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Pairlist-objects) from R documentation states this:

> Pairlists are handled in the R language in exactly the same way as generic vectors (“lists”). In particular, elements are accessed using the same `[[]]` syntax. ***The use of pairlists is deprecated since generic vectors are usually more efficient to use.*** When an internal pairlist is accessed from R it is generally (including when subsetted) converted to a generic vector.