# Check for missing argument in parent function

Tags: r, environment

### Question

I have a function `f` that calculates a summary of the environment in which it is called. In this trivial example it just sums all the objects found.

```
f <- function(){
   x <- ls(parent.frame())
   sum(sapply(x, get, envir=parent.frame()))
}
g <- function(x = 7, y){
    z <- 3
    f()
}
```

However, if called from within a function with missing arguments it will throw an error.

```
R> g(y = 34)
[1] 44

R> g()
Error in FUN(c("x", "y", "z")[[2L]], ...) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

To deal with it appropriately, I need a method to tell, from within `f`, if `y` or some other arbitrary object in the environment of `g` is an argument to `g` and in that case if it is missing.

### My attempts so far

To try different solutions I do

```
debug(f)
g()
```

Of course `missing(y)` does not work since `y` is not an argument to `f`. Changing the environment in which `missing` is evaluated doesn't work either, since we are still on the same level of the call stack:

```
Browse[2]> eval(missing(y), parent.frame())
Error in missing(y) : 'missing' can only be used for arguments

Browse[2]> identical(sys.frames(), eval(sys.frames(), parent.frame()))
[1] TRUE
```

What I can do is determine if `y` is an argument to `g` function using a dirty hack

```
Browse[2]> eval(substitute(missing(a), list(a="x")), parent.frame())
[1] TRUE

Browse[2]> eval(substitute(missing(a), list(a="y")), parent.frame())
[1] TRUE

Browse[2]> eval(substitute(missing(a), list(a="z")), parent.frame())
[1] FALSE
```

that yields `TRUE` for both arguments `x` and `y` but not the ordinary variable `z`. Combining it with a `tryCatch` that checks if the argument can be retrieve would solve the problem, but it is terribly dirty:

```
is.argument <- eval(substitute(missing(a), list(a="y")), parent.frame())
if(is.argument){
    tryCatch({
        get("y", parent.frame())
        FALSE
    }, error = function(e) TRUE)
} else {
    NA
}
```

Moreover, I cannot figure out how to define `is.argument` for an arbitrary argument, as opposed to the explicitly stated `"y"` in the example above.

### Update: Purpose

In reality, the purpose of `f` is to debug `g` during runtime. I might call

```
R> debug(g)
R> g()
```

step through it and inspect the state of the objects with `f`, or I might set `options(error=recover)` and just find myself debugging `g` if it produced an error. In both cases there should be a clearly defined call stack, so I guess my underlying question is if it can be queried on different levels, in a similar way to the frame stack (accessed with `sys.frames()`). I must confess though that this is deep waters for me.

Think of `f` as my own tweaked version of `ls.str`, which can be used like this:

```
Browse[2]> ls.str()   # Inside g()
x :  num 7
y : <missing>
```

After some digging in `ls.str` and `utils:::print.ls_str` I found out that it accomplishes the same task by

```
for (nam in x) {
    cat(nam, ": ")
    o <- tryCatch(get(nam, envir = E, mode = M), error = function(e) e)
    if (inherits(o, "error")) {
        cat(if (length(grep("missing|not found", o$message)))
            "<missing>"
        else o$message, "\n", sep = "")
    } else {
        strO <- function(...) str(o, ...)
        do.call(strO, strargs, quote = is.call(o) || is.symbol(o))
    }
}
```

Unless there is a proper way to do this I'll just make a similar hack.

Comment: Isn't this an issue for `g()` and not `f()`? `y` is an argument *to* the former and if the argument is missing `g()` should act accordingly *before* calling `f()`.

Comment: In most cases I would agree, but the purpose of my `f` is to facilitate debugging of other functions that may not have been written by myself.

Comment: @Backlin If that's the case then how are you going to call `f` from within those functions?

Comment: Just a min, since the underlying reason for performing what I ask for is apparently not clear I'll update the question with a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: Is testing for missingness enough? What do you want to happen if `g()` has a formal named `y` and also assigns to a variable named `y` within its body? Should `y` then be run through the sapply loop in `f()`, or not?

Comment: Good point! The objective of `f` is to provide a more human readable snapshot of the state a function, environment, or even data.frame is in, so if a formal has been overwritten by an assigned variable I'd like to return the assigned variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of missing arguments are represented in the pairlist associated with an environment by an odd object known as the "empty symbol". It turns out that, at least at present, the "empty symbol" is also returned by a call to `quote(expr=)`. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16740307/980833) for one discussion of the empty symbol.)

The function `ls_safe()` uses both of those facts to implement an alternative test of missingness. It returns a character vector of non-missing variables present in the environment specified by its `pos` argument.

```
ls_safe <- function(pos=1) {
    ## Capture the parent environment's frame as a list
    ll <- as.list(parent.frame(pos))
    ## Check for "missing" variables
    ii <- sapply(ll, function(X) identical(X, quote(expr=)))
    names(ll)[!ii]
}

## Then just use ls_safe() in place of ls()
f <- function(){
    x <- ls_safe(pos=2)
    sum(sapply(x, get, envir=parent.frame()))
}

g <- function(x = 7, y){
    z <- 3
    f()
}

g(99)
## [1] 102
g(99, 1000)
## [1] 1102
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: wanting a function that checks if an argument is missing. I also first tried the `eval`-based idea, which always gave me `FALSE` even when the variable was missing.

Josh provided a solution above, but it is too specific. What I wanted was a neat checker function I can add to my functions, so that they check for missingness in necessary variables and throws informative errors. Here's my solution:

```
check_missing = function(var_names, error_msg = "[VAR] was missing! Please supply the input and try again.") {

  #parent.frame as list
  pf = as.list(parent.frame())

  #check each if missing
  for (name in var_names) {
    #is it there at all?
    if (!name %in% names(pf)) {
      stop(name + " is not even found in the parent.frame! Check the variable names!", call. = F)
    }

    #check if missing
    if (are_equal(pf[[name]], quote(expr = ))) {
      stop(str_replace(error_msg, pattern = "\\[VAR\\]", name), call. = F)
    }
  }

  #all fine
  return(invisible(NULL))
}
```

To test it, use this:

```
test_func = function(y) {
  check_missing("y")
  print("OK")
}
```

Test it:

```
test_func(y = )
# Error: y was missing! Please supply the input and try again.
# Called from: check_missing("y")
test_func(y = "k")
# [1] "OK"
```

The remaining thing I'm unsatisfied with is that the error has the wrong "Called from" message. It returns the checker function itself, but it would be more informative if it returned the parent function. I don't know if this can be fixed.

Hope this may be of use to someone.

Comment: Nice function! It solves a different problem than mine though, because you need to tell `test_func` the name of the argument you want to check.

Comment: You can just loop over all of arguments and check for identity with `quote(expr = )`. I did not want to do this because my functions often allow some arguments to be missing.